# pyosmium - Build a Geojson linestring based on OSM Relation

Tags: python, openstreetmap, pyosmium

I have a python script to analyse OSM data, and the objective is to build a `GeoJson` with specific data issued from OSM **relation**.

I'm currently focusing on OSM relation that represents 'hiking' trail like [this one](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/104369).

According to the [document](https://docs.osmcode.org/pyosmium/latest/ref_osm.html?highlight=relation#osmium.osm.Relation.members):

> *members*
> (read-only) Ordered list of relation members. See osmium.osm.RelationMemberList.

the relation object has an attribute `members` which collects all members of the relation.

Hence The first part of the script manages to extract all relation that have a tag `sac_scale=hiking` and collects all its ways.

The following script is on purpose focusing only on 1 specific relation : *r104369*

```py
class HikingWaysfromRelations(osmium.SimpleHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HikingWaysfromRelations, self).__init__()
        self.dict = {}

    def _getWays(self, elem, elem_type):
        # tag
        if 'sac_scale' in elem.tags and elem.tags['sac_scale']=='hiking' and elem.id==104369:

            list=[]
            for mem in elem.members:
                if mem.type=="w":
                    list.append(str(mem.ref))
            self.dict["r"+str(elem.id)]=list
        else:
            pass
    
    def relation(self,r):
        self._getWays(r, "relation")

ml = HikingWaysfromRelations()
ml.apply_file('../pbf/new-zealand.osm.pbf')
```

The result is a dictionary containing the expected relation as the only key, and its ways:

```py
{"r104369": ["191668175", "765285136", "765285135", "765285138", "765285139", "191668225", "765542429", "765542430", "765542432", "765542431", "765542435", "765542436", "765542434", "765542433", "765542437", "765542438", "765542439", "765542440", "765542441", "765542442", "765548983", "271277386", "765548985", "765548984", "684295241", "684295239", "464603363", "464603364", "464607430", "299788481", "178920047", "155711655", "155711646", "684294192", "259362037", "684294189", "259362038", "259362041", "259362036", "259362043", "259362039", "259362040"]}
```

Now the question is: How to build a `GeoJson` containing a single Feature `MultiLineString` that connects all those ways and rebuild the expected hiking trail?

[image]

Based on what I've found on the net, I should re-run a `simpleHander` on the full *.pbf* file, and each time I encounter a way I'm looking for - based on the values of the above dictionary - I could reconstruct a `LineString` with:

```py
import shapely.wkb as wkblib

wkbfab = osmium.geom.WKBFactory()

def getRelationGeometry(elem):
    wkb=wkbfab.create_linestring(elem)
    return wkb
```

The issue is that it looks like some ways have only 1 node, hence triggering following error:

```py
RuntimeError: need at least two points for linestring (way_id=155711655)
```

So what would be the solution to re-build a `GeoJson` feature - `multiLineString` - of multiple ways, to be able to plot the result on https://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0 ?

How for instance openstreetmap manages to re-build the track of a relation when I hit [link](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/104369#map=12/-39.1345/175.6182) if not by connecting all nodes (from all ways) issued from the relation ?

Thanks a lot for your help

I know there is way with bash, where you first filter the initial pbf by keeping only relation with the tag `sac_scale=hiking`, and then transforming this filtered result to GeoJson - but I really want to be able to generate the same with python to understand how OSM data are stored. I just can't figure out an easy way to do so, knowing pyosmium is equivalent (supposedly) to osmium, I believe there should be an easy way there too

```
osmium export output/output_food-drinks.pbf -f geojson
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the way with the id shown in the error in your post (155711655), it has two nodes, not one. Visible [here](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/155711655) as of the time of this answer.

Knowing that, I can think of two reasons why you would get that error:

1. You're not passing in the argument `location=True` to the `apply_file` method as suggested by the [documentation](https://docs.osmcode.org/pyosmium/latest/intro.html#handling-geometries):

   > Because of the way that OSM data is structured, osmium needs to internally cache node geometries, when the handler wants to process the geometries of ways and areas. The apply_file() method cannot deduce by itself if this cache is needed. Therefore locations need to be explicitly enabled by setting the locations parameter to True:
   >
   > `h.apply_file("test.osm.pbf", locations=True, idx='flex_mem')`

   Looking at your code above, the apply_file method only has the input file as an argument, so I think this is likely your problem.
2. The way may be referencing a node that is missing in your pbf extract. This is simple to verify with the osmium cli tool:

   ```
   osmium check-refs <your pbf file>
   ```

   This is the result I get from running that on a valid pbf of my own

   ```
   There are 6702885 nodes, 431747 ways, and 2474 relations in this file.
   Nodes in ways missing: 0
   ```

   Note the `Nodes in ways missing: 0`.